# Linear regression model assumptions

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Linear regression models have to follow 2 key assumptions: (1)error terms are iid and each follows normal distribution with zero mean and variance sigma^2 (2)the matrix X has to be non-random and full column rank. However, I am confused why can we assume the error terms are normally distributed? Also, does the second assumption implies that all the explanatory variables are independent to others? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write the assumptions out using the acronym **LINE** to make the assumptions simple and easy to remember.

1. *Linearity*. We assume that each independent variable $X_i$ is linearly related to the dependent variable $Y$. If this condition is not met, linear regression is considered to be inappropriate. We may transform our data to ensure that $X_i$ and $Y$ are approximately linearly related.
2. *Independence*. We assume that each of our observations are independent of one another. (It is sometimes written that the $y_i$ are independent of one another or that the $\varepsilon_i$ are independent of one another.)
3. *Normality*. We assume that the error terms are Normally distributed. While it is possible to fit a linear regression model to data where the errors are not Normally distributed (much like it's *possible* to fit a linear regression model to data that clearly do not follow a linear trend), this is inadvisable and linear regression is seen as inappropriate. There are other regression models (*generalized linear models* is the term that is typically used) that are appropriate in cases where the error terms are not Normally distributed.
4. *Equality of Variances*. We assume that the data points are homoscedastic - that is, equally scattered about the linear regression line, regardless of the value of the $X_i$ variables. If the data are heteroscedastic - the variance is not equal for all values of $X_i$, then our analyses that rely on Normality are inappropriate. It is possible to use *robust standard errors* (also known as Huber-White standard errors) to correct for this if this assumption doesn't hold.

While it makes sense for $X$ to be of full rank, this does not necessarily need to be the case. There are numerous benefits to $X$ being of full rank and it allows for maximum interpretability. However, one can conduct inference on parameters without $X$ being of full rank.  There are also methods (i.e. PCA) that are designed to take non-independent IVs and project them such that they will be independent in your analysis.

To your question above, we *can* assume that the error terms are iid $Normal(0,\sigma^2)$, **but only if this assumption makes sense.** If you know from the subject material or from your data that the assumptions of independence, Normality, or equality of variances are violated, then perhaps a linear regression model is not appropriate. (While not encapsulated in your question, the linearity assumption is also very important.)  In this case, I would suggest looking into ways to transform your data to ensure the conditions are met or research different types of models (i.e. generalized linear models) that are designed to account for data that do not follow the four **LINE** assumptions mentioned above.

Answer (score -1):

1. Linear regression does not assume any distribution on the errors whatsoever. they can be drawn from any distribution i.i.d or not.
2. X has to be deterministic and of full rank - Yes
3. Also, does the second assumption implies that all the explanatory variables are independent to others? - please elaborate as I don't understand the question

Comment: Thanks for answering. Do you mean there is no specific assumption for error terms in linear regression model? From what I have read so far, people always assume error terms are iid and follow normal distribution with zero mean and sigma^2 variance; is that just a common assumption that everyone uses?

Comment: Sorry for being unclear on my last question. I want to ask does deterministic and of full rank implies that all the X0,.., Xn has are independent to each other given our regression model is Y=a+b1x1+...+bnxn ?

Comment: Also, I would want to know what would happen if the model violates one or more than one of the assumptions?

Comment: 1. No there's no specific assumption on the error.

Comment: 2. The matrix X is deterministic. So I don't understand the independent question. 3. If the matrix X is not full rank your estimation would have to be based on only a subspace of $X^tX$. If the error is not white Gaussian the least squares estimation will not necessary be optimal in terms of mean squared error

Comment: As far as I know in linear regression the full rank of $X$ isn't a assumption. The full rank is only needed to get one rigourus estimator for the parameter vector. With the $i.i.d$ assumption I agree Nir Regev, but with the assumption of normal distributed errors you have the opportunity to calculate exact hypothesis tests and confidence intervals.

Comment: @Daniel : The full rank is an assumption, when and if violated does not allow you to estimate the parameter vector as is, but just a linear combination of the parameters reflecting the column space of X. Moreover, the Gaussian assumption is not needed, though it is more "convenient" to assume it.

Comment: @Nir Regev: Of course for the calculation it makes absoloutely no sense to don't have full rank. But in my opinion it's not necessary for laying down the model before you start the calculation. And also with no gaussian assumption you have to use limit statements and the test theory only counts approximately.

Comment: @Daniel yes I agree.

Comment: Full rank is not necessary as long as you restrict your attention to estimable functions of the parameter vector.  Indedendence of error terms is quite essential for valid inferences on estimable functions of the parameter vector. And normality of residuals is quite essential for validity of the usual prediction intervals.